# how to do mean made up of sum of few variables in R

Tags: r, mean

2=female, 1=male. q1, q2, q3 are variables.
I want to know what is the ratio between male and female. For example: the ratio of the first is 2/3=0.66. The same answer for the second.
About the third, i need to divide in 2 because `-99` is missing value and the answer should be 1/2=0.5. how can i do it?

```
q1      q2      q3
2.00    1.00    1.00
2.00    1.00    1.00
2.00    1.00    -99.00
```

Answer (score 1):

If `df` is your `data.frame` or `matrix`, you could calculate the sums of `1` appearances per row and divide by the sums of non `-99` appearances

```
rowSums(df == 1)/rowSums(df != -99)
# [1] 0.6666667 0.6666667 0.5000000
```

You could wrap it up into `round` if you like.

It is also probably better to convert missing values to `NA`s using something like

```
is.na(df) <- df == -99
```

And then

```
rowSums(df == 1, na.rm = TRUE)/rowSums(!is.na(df))
```

---

As a side note, I don't know what is your data structure but in most cases it is better to work with matrices if you only have numerical values there.

Answer (score 0):

First, change the encoding of the NA values from `-99`to an actual `NA`value. That way you can easily exclude it from any method.

I would then also just change the value for female to `0`. The you can just calculate your ratio by summing up the rows and dividing by the number of columns, excluding those with `NA`.